# What does "9.5% fulfilled commitment" mean?

Tags: discussion

I noticed @lkessler's [hope](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/what-is-the-average-activation-time-for-a-site) ;-) that genealogy.se would break the record for least time in beta. Since record is 32 days and we are now at day 30, I decided to look at the [beta scorecard](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy) (which changed recently to include a subjective rating like 'excellent' and 'needs work').

I noticed on the sidebar a line that said

> 9.5% fulfilled commitment

Does anyone know what this means?

It doesn't appear to be one of 5 criteria that determine whether genealogy is closed/kept-in-beta/launched but I assume it's something we would hope would trend upward. But what is it and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 2):

No, I wasn't hoping for the least time in beta. Beta is always a minimum of 90 days, and then more if required.

I was hoping to break the least time **to get to** beta. That mean't getting through the Area51 Definition and Commitment phases the fastest.

As it turns out, we took 20 days in Definition and 31 days in Commitment for a total of 51 days. Definition was hampered by needing to finish getting the 40 questions with 10 votes each. Commitment was hampered by needing to finish getting the 100 committers with 200+ rep on Stack Exchange sites.

[The record of fastest proposal to beta launch](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6332/what-is-the-average-activation-time-for-a-site) time was Mathematica at 32 days, so our 51 days did not break that.

Now, re your question: What is 9.5% fulfilled commitment.

Everyone who committed pledged to participate in the beta and ask or answer at least 10 questions during the beta.

We had 263 committers when we went to beta. So far, 9.5% or 25 of them have fulfilled the commitment and have asked or answered their 10 questions.

The goal, of course, is that 100% of people who committed fulfill their commitment.

However [using stats from Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history) and from a sample of our committers, I estimate that after the 30 days we've been in beta:

- 25 committers have fulfulled commitment (asked/answered at least 10 questions)
- 73 committers have asked/answered from 1 to 9 questions
- 116 committers have signed up to the beta but have not asked/answered any questions
- 49 committers have not even signed up to the beta.

I'm actually very disappointed with those 116 + 49 committers.

Comment: Only half of the followers signed up for beta. It's a little sad considering how much work you put into recruiting them.

Comment: @Luke - I think if the moderators had a way to email those 165 people and send them a "2nd notice", that would entice half of them to get involved. These are people who are interested. They've mostly forgotten about us. We just need some way of notifying them again to remind them.

Comment: Is there any way to find what they were interested in and entice them that way. Ie have all the questions asked on area51 been asked in beta? As opposed to 'mass email', is there any way to get the system to send a directed email that says to an individual 'you asked x on area51, you can now ask it to wider audience on beta site blah blah'?

Comment: @Duncan - That's good thinking outside the box, and I'd like to hear more ideas like that. Unfortunately, most of the people did not have any activity at Area51 other than their committment. Many of them only have their name in their profile (some just their first name) and nothing else. For those with Stack Exchange experience, tracking them down on others sites and trying to contact them through comments on their posts is laborous and is technically not allowed.

Comment: It is allowed in chat (as most things are).